# Integration gives inequality

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

The book I am reading makes a claim I don't understand

Suppose that $p(x,\xi) \in C(\bar{\Omega},\mathbb{R})$, and define $P(x,\xi) = \int_0^{\xi}p(x,t)\ dt$.
Assume further that there are $\mu > 2$ and $r\geq 0$ such that for all $|\xi| \geq r$, $$0<\mu P(x,\xi) < \xi p(x,\xi)$$

Here is the claim : Integration of this condition shows that there are constants $A,B > 0$ such that $$P(x,\xi) \geq A|\xi|^{\mu} - B $$

Could you please explain why this is true?  Integrating: what exactly and in what variable?

Comment: Could you clarify the definition of $P$? What goes into $p$ inside the integral?

Comment: @PavelM Yes, it has been edited.

Comment: I'm sure it must be easy... I'm just missing something.

Comment: Look at the derivative of $\xi^{-\mu} P(x,\xi)$ with respect to $\xi$.

Comment: It was really easy.  Thanks