# Integration of the inequality?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, partial-differential-equations

Suppose that $p(x,\xi) \in C(\bar{\Omega},\mathbb{R})$, and define $P(x,\xi) = \int_0^{\xi}p(x,t)\ dt$.
Assume further that there are $\mu > 2$ and $r\geq 0$ such that for all $|\xi| \geq r$, $$0<\mu P(x,\xi) < \xi p(x,\xi)$$

Here is the claim : Integration of this condition shows that there are constants $A,B > 0$ such that $$P(x,\xi) \geq A|\xi|^{\mu} - B $$

Could you please explain why this is true?  Integrating... what exactly and in what variable?

This question was asked 7 years ago by **Euler....IS_ALIVE** in [Integration gives inequality](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/275561/integration-gives-inequality) 
but the answer was not given ... please can anyone know the key to calculate this integral it would be of great help.

Here is what I did :
Let $r>0$, then for any $\xi \in \mathbb{R}$ with $|\xi|\geq r>0$
$$\mu \leq \frac{\xi p(x,\xi)}{P(x,\xi)}.$$
Suppose $\xi >r$, dividing by $\xi$ ,
$$\frac{\mu}{\xi}\leq \frac{p(x,\xi)}{P(x,\xi)}$$ 
Integrating both terms in $[r,\xi]$,
$$\int^{\xi}_{r}\frac{\mu}{s} ds \leq \int^{\xi}_{r} \frac{p(x,s)}{P(x,s)} ds$$ 
Then,
$$[\ln{s^{\mu}}]^{\xi}_{r} \leq \int^{\xi}_{r} \frac{p(x,s)}{P(x,s)} ds$$
and from here on i dont know what to do...

Comment: Have you tried to follow the hint given in the comments to the linked question?

Comment: I did follow the hints @MaoWao but no use ... surly I'm missing something.

Comment: Then please write down your attempt and where exactly it failed.

Comment: I added what  I did @MaoWao ... I stopped because I didn't know what to do to get to the result wanted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ingredient you're missing is that $P(x,\xi)=\int_0^\xi p(x,t)\,dt$ implies $\partial_\xi P(x,\xi)=p(x,\xi)$ by the fundamental theorem of calculus. Thus
$$
\int_r^\xi \frac{p(x,s)}{P(x,s)}\,ds=\int_r^\xi \frac{\partial_s P(x,s)}{P(x,s)}\,ds=\int_r^\xi \partial_s \ln P(x,s)\,ds=[\ln P(x,s)]^\xi_r.
$$
Hence your inequality reads
$$
[\ln s^\mu]_r^\xi\geq [\ln P(x,s)]_r^\xi,
$$
and exponentiation yields the desired result.

Comment: thank you @MaoWao  it's exactly what I missed ... it is only I made a mistake concerning the inequality is actually $\leq$ not $\geq$.